# Authenticated HTTP POST call to Firestore

Tags: firebase, http, post, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

We have a service that sends HTTP POST request every 15 minutes. We have set it up to send data to Firestore successfully. It creates a new document every 15 minutes. We just need to make the POST requests **authenticated**.

Some more details about our situation:

It is a meteo IoT project. We have wireless weather stations built on arduino.

1. These weather stations send weather data to a Sigfox cloud service.
2. In Sigfox Cloud we have set up a HTTP POST to send the weather data to firestore (and also firebase realtime database)
3. We have a web app that shows these weather data to a logged in user.

So there should be a way for the weather stations (sigfox http posts) to authenticate. Each user can have access to multiple weather stations.

I read the firebase documentation but with no luck.

I will be very grateful to anyone able to help us.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase already offered Security rules for READ and WRITE. You can enable the security rules in Firebase console. Please refer the document for more details https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started